# "No module named wordcloud" after successful installation

Tags: python-3.x, import, pycharm, python-import

After searching everywhere on here I found some solutions to my problem. At first, the [error was](https://imgur.com/V948WzF) that I needed Visual C++ 14.0 and that I could get it from a link that didn't work. So, I downloaded Visual C++ Build Tools and got Visual C++ 14.0.23026. That did not solve the problem.

I did some more searching and found that I could install it using wheel. So, I got wheel and got the .whl file from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#wordcloud) as shown in the comments of [this](https://www.bountysource.com/issues/31735571-wordcloud-fails-to-install-with-pip-under-windows-10-python-3-5-anaconda)
post, making sure to get the correct version for my python version (3.6). Running `python -m pip install wordcloud-1.5.0-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl` worked, [it seemed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rH1h.jpg).

However, after restarting Pycharm, the IDE I use to run python files, it still didn't import it correctly. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wordcloud'`.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

EDIT: It works outside of Pycharm (just double clicking my python file), but I'd still like it to work in Pycharm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and I've solved it.

When you create a project, you should choose 'inherit global site-packages
[image: Here is the screenshot]

Or

You can use the terminal in the Pycharm to install the wordcloud.
[image: Here is the screenshot]

You can also install wordcloud by File->Settings->Project:your project name->Project interpreter.
[image: Here is the screenshot]